# Loop that formats an API query based on key value in a list and then paginate through each one of those queries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary within a list of objects, and I'm trying to grab the value of the "state" key in this list. When I grab the value of the "state" key, I want to parse that key into an API query. When the API does the query, I want to paginate through those results, and then move on to the next "state" key. I just can't wrap my head around how I'd do this. Here's what I have so far.

```
api_url = api.taxes.info.net/taxes/%s/rate?page=1

list =[
{"state": "Ohio", 
"state": "California",
"state": "Georgia"}
      ]                
 
tax_rates = []

for i in list:
    state = i.get("state") #grabs the value of the "state" key
    r = requests.get(api_url % state) #pasrses the state into the url string format
    pagination= r.links.get('next', {}).get('url') #api has link headers available that can go through
        while pagination != None:
            tax_rates.extend([item for item in response.json()])
        
print(tax_rates)
```

When I try to print the results in my list (tax_rates), I get an empty list. I'm not really confident in my coding ability, so I'm pretty sure there's some logic that I'm not putting together properly.

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(repr(pagination))` after `pagination = r.links.get(...`?

Comment: I get "None" value

Comment: @mkrieger1 Some of the "states" won't have any additional pages so the link header won't exist. I think that's whats happening here. But how do I move on to append the next "state" key when there aren't any pagination results is what I'm stuck on.